# Save Bokeh interactive plot to HTML file

Tags: bokeh, interactive

I created a bokeh app with Select functionality and vbar chart in it. when i run the app on a bokeh server 
using *bokeh serve --show myapp.py* the program runs successfully.
But when i try to save the same app as a HTML using **output_file("Test.html"), Save()** I'm able to successfully generate the HTML, but the Dropdown/ Select functionality and the interactivity is missing. Can someone advise if i'm missing something please.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to save Bokeh server applications as plain HTML. When you use the `Select` widget in a Bokeh server app, that triggers *real Python code* to execute.  Browsers displaying plain HTML have no capability to run Python code! The Bokeh server ***is the Python process*** that executes the Python code for your `Select.on_change` widget callback. A Bokeh server must be running for the `Select` widget to trigger Python callback code when it is changed.

If you don't need to run actual Python code, then you could have a *JavaScript* callback for the `Select` widget using `Select.js_on_change` and a `CustomJS` callback instead. That could be saved as HTML (because it's *just* HTML and JavaScript).